# I get errors when typing the @SidedProxy. What happened?

Tags: eclipse, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am making a Minecraft Mod with Eclipse Mars and I got errors when typing the following:

`@SidedProxy(clientSide  = Reference.CLIENT_PROXY_CLASS, serverSide = Reference.SERVER_PROXY_CLASS)`

What did I do wrong? It said "the attribute clientSide/serverSide is undefined for the annotation type SidedProxy" .

I cannot run Minecraft to test my mod without it, so I need to fix this error.

Comment: What's with people putting incorrect tags?

Answer (score 0):

For a definitive answer you need to give us more information.
What version of minecraft forge are you using?
Have you correctly imported SidedProxy?

In eclipse, hold <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and click on @SidedProxy to open where it is declared, and check that you are using the correct attribute names (it may have changed between versions, so you may need to put something different)